# How to curve the mesh without using bezier?

Tags: modeling, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

i have a little problem in blender. How can i curve the mesh like the image below without using bezier.

[image]

Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

Various Features you can explore

- Proportional Edit with a suitable vertex density so there are more vertices to bend
- Use a portion of a torus
- Use a portion of Cylinder with Solidify Modifier
- Curve Modifier and apply on top portion first and isolated
- Link to Tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MrNVVHdKd3E

Answer (score 2):

You can use "Simple deform" modifier for bending or bevel it in edit mode.